# How to set JS-Syntax for .js.php-Extension in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: php, sublime-text-2, syntax-highlighting

I have several js-Files (and css-Files), which need php-Commands. So I changed the extension to .js.php or .css.php

But when I open the file in Sublime Text 2, I always have to change the syntax highlighting manually to Javascript, because ST2 only recognises the .php

Is there a way to tell ST2 that "js.php" is Javascript-Code, without changing it manually all the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) via Package Control.  Add a rule to the ApplySyntax user settings (*Preferences > Package Settings > ApplySyntax > Settings - User*)

```
 "syntaxes": [
  {
    "name": "JavaScript/JavaScript",
    "rules": [
      {"file_name": ".*\\.js\\.php$"}
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "CSS",
    "rules": [
      {"file_name": ".*\\.css\\.php$"}
    ]
  }
]
```

file_name =  regex for the file extension

name = folder and filename without extension of the syntax's tmLanguage (from the Packages folder)

This will only take effect for newly opened files. Already opened files will not update.

Comment: thanks, works perfectly. Haven't thought I would get an answer